Screen blinking after boot and before login
Unlike the screen flicker that suggested to be solved with
 sudo kernelstub -a "i915.enable_psr=0"
or
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=1"
My screen blinks black, gray, black, and gray before the login screen. I have experienced this problem in Ubuntu 23.10 and Pop_OS 22.04 (NVIDIA version). Between Ubuntu and Pop_OS installations, I have completely cleared the SSD and formatted it with the Windows Disk Manager. Then I removed the SSD that has Windows installed on it and performed a clean installation of both distros.
It happened during regular use with freshly updated NVIDIA drivers using a 3060 GPU. Boot takes longer than usual, but systemd-analyze shows lower time results, so I am suspecting that the device boots regularly but there is a display problem.
I tried with Wayland and Xorg for Ubuntu.
The device also has Windows on another SSD, which boots as expected without any blinking.
